# ng build can't find typescript module from Git Bash

Tags: angular, git, typescript, npm

While trying to run `ng build` from **Git Bash** I get the following error, even after successfully running `npm install -g typescript.`

Where should I install `typescript` so that Git recognizes it?

**Error**

```
$ npm install -g typescript
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc -> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsserver -> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
+ typescript@3.7.4
updated 1 package in 1.884s

...

$ ng build
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\angular-cli-master\lib\bootstrap-local.js:6:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an NPM cache issue. Try running `npm ci` from the root of your project and see if that solves it.

Note: This requires npm 5.7.1 or newer.

If your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files are out of sync, this will fail. Ensure you have a typescript entry in your `package.json`, run `npm install` to sync them up again, and then run `npm ci` again.